# Datatable Jquery Imprimir Elementos Especificos

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-datatables, datatable

Como imprimir elementos especificos de fora do datatable?

Aqui está um [JSFIDDLE](https://jsfiddle.net/ms85e7zo/) de exemplo

Eu queria que quando apertasse o botão `PRINT`, essa `div` abaixo seja impressa tambem

```
<div id="PRINT_HERE_TOO" class="test">
   <h1>
      Print Here Too!
   </h1>
</div>
```

Fui claro? Obrigado!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Penso que seja isto que queres:

https://jsfiddle.net/ms85e7zo/3/

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').DataTable( {
          dom: 'Bfrtip',
        buttons: [
            {
                extend: 'print',
                messageTop: $("#PRINT_HERE_TOO").html()
               }
        ]
    } );
```

Comment: Sua solução é boa, mas essa configuração acredito que tenha que ser dentro das configurações do datatable, porque se há mais de 1 página nesta solução, o print não vem com todas as páginas.

Comment: editei a resposta

Comment: Shooow, perfeito cara! Obrigado!

Comment: Pq não pegou o css?A cor rosa não saiu ao imprimir.